# Forcing installation order using zef

Tags: module, raku, zef

Lately, installing LWP::Simple requires the prior installation of IO::Socket::SSL, as is shown in this [Travis log](https://travis-ci.org/perl6/doc/jobs/442307262). However, there does not seem to be a way of forcing `zef` to install them in that particular order. The only way I can think of is to list it before in the `depends` section of `META6.JSON`, but that does not seem to work.

The only slightly related solution I have found is [this one](https://github.com/ugexe/zef/issues/107), but that does not provide a solution, rather reports an (old and already fixed) bug.
Also, dependencies in the different phases (`build`, for instance) all seem to be blended together and installed in, I guess, dependence first order.
So, other than listing IO::Socket::SSL as a dependency in `LWP::Simple`, or forcing installation via another direct command before, is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module author does not get a say towards dependency installation order. A naive solution of doing them in order would not be parallelization friendly.

As to the actual problem of the failing tests -- how is this not a bug in `LWP::Simple`? The tests clearly fail due to missing IO::Socket::SSL, so either IO::Socket::SSL should be added to its test-depends, or its [test](https://github.com/raku-community-modules/LWP-Simple/blob/1ea92f84d9dcea20c3dcef6b585cfff71fdff19d/t/getstore.t#L15) should be fixed to not point at a url that forwards to https (before the skip-all test for IO::Socket::SSL is done 4 lines below).

Comment: It might be a bug, since it's not forcing to process it as a dependency. However, sometimes you have to work around those bugs

Comment: It is a CI environment, so the workaround is simple -- `zef install IO::Socket::SSL && zef install . --deps-only`. If you want to work around a problem dependency as a module author -- depend on a different module that isn't broken or fix upstream.